# How can I get Singletons from @Provides method?

Tags: java, groovy, singleton, guice

I have Module with `@Provides` method:

```java
class EnvironmentModule extends AbstractModule {

    static String CURRENT_PRODUCT

    @Override
    protected final void configure() {
    }

        @Provides
    static ProcessBuilder get(){
        return CURRENT_PRODUCT == 'Product1' ? new Product1ProcessBuilder() : new Product2ProcessBuilder()
    }
```

Class where I Inject `ProcessBuilder`:

```java
class Operation {

    @Inject
    Provider<ProcessBuilder> processBuilder

    void operate() {
        def process = processBuilder.get().build()
    }
}
```

Step how I execute my test:

1. `CURRENT_PRODUCT = 'Product1'`
2. `operate()` give us instance of prodcut1, e.g `Product1ProcessBuilder@26aecf31`
3. `CURRENT_PRODUCT = 'Product2'`
4. `operate()` give us instance of prodcut2, e.g `Product2ProcessBuilder@4bb4adf7`
5. `CURRENT_PRODUCT = 'Product1'`
6. `operate()` give us instance of prodcut1, e.g `Product1ProcessBuilder@11544ddd`
7. `CURRENT_PRODUCT = 'Product2'`
8. `operate()` give us instance of prodcut2, e.g `Product2ProcessBuilder@38e46ea`

**How can I get the same instance in steps 2), 6) and 4), 8) ?**

When I annotate `@Provides` method with `@Singleton` it always returns the same instance of the first returned product.
When I annotate each class products class with `@Singleton` then I have each time another product.

Comment: I'm no Guice expert but I'd assume it works like the other injection frameworks, i.e. you'd either use a qualifier (e.g. as an annotation) or a parameter to the `get()` method. Alternatively, as in your case, you could return instances based on logic like yours (just keep in mind that you shouldn't compare strings using `==`) and just return the same instance the same string. You're currently creating new instances all the way - so you might want to look into the singleton pattern in general.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I know that currently, I am creating new instances all the way, but as I wrote on the bottom, I tried some options but it is still not work

Comment: Your use of `new` circumvents the injection framework. You'd either need to lookup `Product1ProcessBuilder` etc. inside `get()` to get the singleton instances (preferred option) or create the instances once and return them (have a look at the [general non-injection based pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)). As stated already, I'd prefer option 1 since you'd then be able to use `@Singleton` and the string would just be used as a switch to either lookup `Product1ProcessBuilder` or `Product2ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Option 1 really suits me, thanks for the advice, I will try it!

Comment: @Thomas it's entirely feasible directly with Guice. See my answer. Also, the `new` doesn't circumvent the injection framework since it's done inside the `@Provides` method, which exists specifically to allow custom construction of instances.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire good to know that there's still some interceptor (or something like that) handling injection into instances created with `new` in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EnvironmentModule class your get() method should be:

```
 @Provides
    static ProcessBuilder get(Product1ProcessBuilder product1CommonBorrowOperations, Product2ProcessBuilder product2CommonBorrowOperations) {
        return CURRENT_PRODUCT == 'Product1' ? product1CommonBorrowOperations : product2CommonBorrowOperations
    }
```

Your classes Product1ProcessBuilder and Product2ProcessBuilder also should be annotated with @Singleton  to get same instance in steps 2), 6) and 4), 8)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with just a tad more configuration:

```
@Provides @Singleton @Named("Product1")
static ProcessBuilder provideProduct1ProcessBuilder() {
  return new Product1ProcessBuilder();
}

@Provides @Singleton @Named("Product2")
static ProcessBuilder provideProduct2ProcessBuilder() {
  return new Product2ProcessBuilder();
}

static String CURRENT_PRODUCT;

@Provides static ProcessBuilder get(
    @Named("Product1") ProcessBuilder product1ProcessBuilder,
    @Named("Product2") ProcessBuilder product2ProcessBuilder) {
  // Note the absence of @Singleton
  return "Product1".equals(CURRENT_PRODUCT) ? product1ProcessBuilder : product2ProcessBuilder;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it looks a little complicated, here's a simpler solution

Comment: It's the same answer as the other one... So what do you think is complicated here? It's only more standard Guice as it's consistent by using provider methods everywhere rather than mixing definitions which can confuse code readers.